# Separing a string in separate words

Tags: c++

Take this string:

```
asking  a question    is easy
```

I want in a while loop

- take first word `asking`,
- check something about it with a function,
- then get to the next word `a`
- and so on until the end of the string

Words can be separated by one or more spaces.

**Edit:**

I think I actually made a mistake when explaining. Here what I've been working on:

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"string="; gets(string);
    cout<<"template="; cin>>template;
    while (i<strlen(string))
    {
        k=0;
        while (string[i]!=' ')
        {
            word[k]=string[i];
            i++; k++;
        }
        if (function(string,word)==1) count++;
        while (i<strlen(s) && string[i]==' ')
          i++;
    }
    cout <<"count="<<count;
}
```

I'd like to stick to some old/basic C++ like I do in school.

Answer (score 0):

Stick your string in a `std::stringstream` and then extract words from it in a `while` loop (to check that the stream is still okay):

```
std::string str("asking a question is easy");
std::stringstream ss(str);
std::string word;
while (ss >> word) {
  // Do something
}
```